# How to keep node client server connection open to send data to client whenever something new in node happens via the same route

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to create a connection between client and server in express that only opens once, like normal, but instead of the client pausing everything and waiting for the response before moving on to a different function, it just leaves the connection open but doesn't 'wait' for a response.

Here is what I am essentially trying to do:
Client:

```
var a = {currentUser: auth.currentUser.uid};
$.post('/generateRealtimeUpdatesStudent', a, function (data, status) {
   someFunctionThatCallsEveryTimeTheServerSendsToClientNewStuff();
});
```

Server:

```
app.post('/generateRealtimeUpdatesStudent', function(req, res) {
  var currentUser = req.body.currentUser;
  db.collection('Messaging').where('Users',  'array-contains', currentUser).onSnapshot((querySnap) => {
    const doc = querySnap.docChanges()[0].doc;
        const data = querySnap.docChanges()[0].doc.data();
    var theObj = {id: doc.id, User1: data.User1, User2: data.User2, Users: data.Users, Last: data.Last, Created: data.Created, User1Messages: data.User1Messages, User2Messages: data.User2Messages }
    res.send(theObj);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    var dataToSend = {Error:"yes"};
    res.json(dataToSend);   
  })
});
```

I am using firebase. What that function does, is whenever something in the database changes, like a new message is sent, etc, that function will trigger and then send whatever was changed to the client via res.send(obj);

However, there are 2 problems with this.

1. The client side function that has $.post() to initialize the connection waits for a response (that res.send() in the server) to move on and continue in the js page.
2. The connection closes once that res.send() in the server happens, thus the realTimeUpdates only is good for one use. I know I can solve this by just recalling that client side function, soo this isnt an issue more a preference that saves time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to repeatedly update data you should use WebSockets. There are some libraries out there (e.g. [Socket.IO](https://socket.io)) that make it really easy.