# How To Listen to Firestore changes from NodeJs express server to send Multipe Resonse

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-cloud-firestore, server

I'm Using React js requesting from the server to get an array of data and updates for each change in the collection, node js, and express is the server side and I'm using Admin SDK to fetch the data from Firebase, Here is the code.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () =>{

            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/orders/order', 
            body,{
                  headers:{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json",
                    Authorization: 'Bearer' + token
                  }
                })
                    
                setData(res.data.list)
                
            }
      
    fetchData()
  },[])
```

***Then in express server Node Js this is how I send the response***

```
app.post('/api/orders/order', async(req, res)=>{

    const ordersDoc = admin.firestore().collection('Orders')

    await ordersDoc.onSnapshot((doc)=>{
        doc.docChanges().forEach(document => {
        if (document.type === 'added') {
            list = []
            list.push({id: document.doc.id, ...document.doc.data()})
            return res.send({list: list})
         }
       if (document.type === 'removed') {
           list = []
           list.push({id: document.doc.id, ...document.doc.data()})
           return res.send({list: list})
         }
      })
        
    })
```

In express, you can't send more than one response to the client for sane request.

***So the question is how to send a response whenever new data is added to Firestore in real-time and send the data back to clint?***

I have tried `res.wright()` but it only send a string and I want to send an array of object + I didn't receive any `response` in react web app.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to first build up the response over all documents, and then send it back at the end of the loop. Something like:

```
app.post('/api/orders/order', async(req, res)=>{
    const ordersCollection = admin.firestore().collection('Orders');

    const querySnapshot = await ordersCollection.get();
  
    const response = querySnapshot.docChanges().map((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
            return { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() };
        }
        if (change.type === 'removed') {
            return { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() };
        }
    })
    return res.send(response);
})
```

Comment: I have to reload the page, and it doesn't detect changes  if I delete or add a document to the collection

Comment: First off: does the code now run without errors when you make the change from my answers? And if so, is it clear to you what I changed, and why that removes the error message you posted? --- If so, you indeed will only get responses once and not continue to listen further. I changed the code to use `get()`, as there's no way to keep sending responses after you called `send`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34521500, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74586459 and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+keep+open+connection+to+send+more+responses

Comment: There is no problem with your code, I have no problem with the error I can solve it the question is this How send a response whenever new data is added to Firestore in real-time and send the data back to the clint,

Comment: `How To Listen to Firestore changes from NodeJs express server to send Multipe Resonse` this is the quistion

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use either server-side events(SSE) or sockets. Either way, you need to maintain a secure connection between the server and the client so that the server can send updates based on any activity in the database using the snapshot feature.

**Note:** Using web sockets is the standard for having near real-time communication between the services but also depends on your exact use case.